# Cannot print results of cgi script in webpage <div> using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to print the result of cgi script inside a `<div>` in html page using the code

**HTML**

```
<b>Already Loaded Data</b>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  var fdate='document.ccform.cdt.value';
  var tdate='document.ccform.cdt.value';
  $( "#result" ).load( "../cgi-bin/coll.cgi?ctype=''&cdet=''&fdt=$fdate&tdt=$tdate" );
</script>
```

Note:- The HTML form name is `ccform` and the date field name is `cdt.Coll.cgi` takes four values which are `ctype`, `cdet`, `fdt` and `tdt`.

`fdt` and `tdt` are dates.

I presume the syntax of date field needs to be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot wrong here. You cannot interpolate variables into strings with `$` this way, and you cannot access values from variables using `'document.ccform.cdt.value'`. You also don't need to supply empty values `('')` for your empty query string variables.

You seem to be lacking an understanding of what strings are and how they work; nothing anywhere in JavaScript would suggest that `'fdt=$fdate'` would be a correct way of building a query string, or that you can access a variable using `'document.ccform'` instead of `document.ccform`. You should read a [tutorial on JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) rather than trying to feel your way around these fundamental syntax issues.

Your code should look something like this:

```
var fdate = document.ccform.cdt.value;
var tdate = document.ccform.cdt.value;
$("#result").load( "../cgi-bin/coll.cgi?ctype=&cdet=&fdt=" + fdate + "&tdt=" + tdate );
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion. It is still not working. Previously with my code I was hitting the script. Now it is not even doing that.

Comment: I totally agree with meagar. Please please learn the basics of JavaScript before you even think of using jQuery as jQuery is just a framework built using the good old JavaScript. This would get you stared on: http://www.newbie.org/JavaScript/

Comment: @Bobby Previously, you were hitting your script with useless values for your variables. You would have been sending through the literal string `...&fdt=document.ccform.cdt.value&...`. Now it's likely that `document.ccform.cdt.value;` is raising an error, because you haven't supplied us with the correct variable names. You're going to have to do some debugging. Open your developer console and look for JavaScript errors, we can't do this for you.

Comment: @Bobby, it'd help us help you better if you posted your html as well.